# How do i play a video through an object on blender 2.8?

Tags: animation, objects, video

does doing this work the same way as of in the stable version of blender 2.79? And another thing is that the video i am wanting to add to a plain is 2 minutes and 44 seconds long is there a duration limit on putting a video on an object?

Comment: have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i play a video through an object on blender 2.8? does doing this work the same way as of in the stable version of
>   blender 2.79?

Yes. **Import >Images as Planes.**

You can also drag and drop as an active empty to bench it.

> And another thing is that the video i am wanting to add to a plain is
>   2 minutes and 44 seconds long is there a duration limit on putting a
>   video on an object?

To my knowledge, no. However, it seems to play slower with large files. my best experience has been when using Eevee. 3 minutes should play fine.

Blender's 2.8 latest build supports this feature.
https://builder.blender.org/download/

Plays butter smooth on my PC.

**Import images as planes is an add-on**

To enable it, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons.

[image]

Comment: oh okay cool that makes sense now i didn't know there was an add on for that thanks for that ill give a go and see what happens.

Comment: If a movie file doesn't update the frames correctly in the viewer, you can put a driver in the Image/movie node's frame offset value. Type in #frame to the value window, it should turn purple. Then the frames will update when scrubbing the timeline.

Comment: @3pointedit how do you put a driver in the image/movie node's? this is my first time trying to do this i didn't really need to know how to do this until i started learning how to use the video sequencer which it kinda of does matter now because i wanna import my own videos i edit or make into my animations.

Comment: Make sure that the image as planes object is selected then opens Shader window, there you'll see a bunch of nodes. Find the movie texture node and at the bottom you'll see the Frame Offset value. In there type- 
#frame   .
The window will turn purple when you press enter. Then it should play back correctly when you change frames. This is just a work around for now, until Blender 2.8 textures get fixed up.